# How to assign global enum as Tag value in XAML?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, enums

I read several questions on the subject, but the answers do not work for me.
I have the following enum that is declared in StlContainer.cs:

```
public enum ToothVisualModelType
{
    CoordinateSystemPivot = 0,
    Tooth = 1,
    Crown = 2,
    Gums = 3
}
```

The enum is declared outside the StlContainer class definition which makes it a global enum. I want to assign its values to the Tag property of different XAML controls, so I tried to do it like this:

```
<xctk:ColorPicker Tag="{x:Static local:ToothVisualModelType.Tooth}" 
                  Name="colorPickerTooth" 
                  Width="110" 
                  Grid.Column="1" 
                  Grid.Row="3" 
                  SelectedColorChanged="colorPickerTooth_SelectedColorChanged" 
                  DisplayColorAndName="True" 
                  Margin="0,0,10,5">
 </xctk:ColorPicker>
```

But got the error:

> Error 1   Unknown build error, 'Key cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: key Line 234 Position 43.'  D:\Visual Studio\Projects\Dental Viewer\Dental Viewer 1.2\Dental Viewer\MainWindow.xaml 234 43  Dental Viewer 1.2

I tried moving the enum to MainWindow.xaml.cs, I tried

```
Tag="{x:Static local:StlContainer+ToothVisualModelType.Tooth}"
```

and

```
Tag="{x:Static MyNamespace:ToothVisualModelType.Tooth}"
```

I tried to assign this to a Tag on a Label control and still get the same error. What am I missing here? Can I use some kind of Binding to workaround this?

PS: When I type in the value and get to `Tag="{x:Static }"` the autocomplete only suggests the  Member parameter to complete it like this `Tag="{x:Static Member=}"` if that even matters.

Comment: How do you definfe `local` namespace in XAML? Is `ToothVisualModelType` in that namespace?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your code `Tag="{x:Static local:ToothVisualModelType.Tooth}"`.. This is absolutely correct...

Comment: @AmolBavannavar This is exactly what I'm fighting with. It should work, but it doesn't. And yes everything is in the same namespace

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution after reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088754/how-to-declare-a-namespace-in-wpf-xaml).
I thought this was done automatically or internally, but the solution is that I have to explicitly declare the `local` namespace in the Window tag like so:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dental_Viewer"
```

Then `<xctk:ColorPicker Tag="{x:Static local:ToothVisualModelType.Tooth}"/>` works like a charm.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use this expression:

```
<Control Name="MyControl"
         Width="100"
         Height="30">

    <Control.Tag>
        <x:Static Member="local:ToothVisualModelType.Tooth" />
    </Control.Tag>
</Control>
```

Or you can create a static class like so:

```
internal static class ToothVisualModelClass
{
    public static string CoordinateSystemPivot = "0";
    public static string Tooth = "1";
    // ...etc...
}
```

In XAML also used like this:

```
Tag="{x:Static local:ToothVisualModelClass.Tooth}"
```